# Storing language and styles. What would be best? Files or DB ( i18N )

Tags: php, database, file, internationalization, storage

I'm starting a Incident Tracking System for IT, and its likely my first PHP project.

I've been designing it in my mind based on software I've seen like vBulletin, and I'd like it to have i18n and styles editables.

So my first question goes here:

1. What is best method to store these things, knowing they will be likely static. I've been thinking about getting file content with PHP, showing it in a text editor, and when save is made, replace the old one. (Making a copy if it hasn't ever been edited before so we have the "original").
   I think this would be considerably faster than using MySQL and storing the language / style.
2. What about security here? Should I create .htaccess for asking for pw on this folder?
3. I know how to make a replace using for each getting an array from database and using strreplace ($name, $value, $file) but if I store language in file, can I make a an associative array with it's content (like a JSON).

Thanks a lot and sorry for so many questions, im newbie

Comment: i would use a db, why do you think it would be slower? db's are designed for fast data selection and retrieval.

Comment: I don't know I have my idea that the lesser queries the best, although I don't know (almost anything) about databases but I already have a book about database design that I will start reading in some weeks.

Answer (score 1):

this is what im doing in my cms:

- for `each` plugin/program/entity (you name it) i develop, i create a `/translations` folder.
- i put there all my translations, named like **el.txt, de.txt, uk.txt** etc. all languages
- i store the translation data in **JSON**, because its easy to store to, easy to read from and easiest for everyone to post theirs.
- files can be easily UTF8 encoded in-file without messing with databases, making it possible to read them in file-mode. (just `JSON.parse` them)
- on installation of such plugins, i just loop through all translations and put them in database, each language per table row. (etc. `a data column of TEXT datatype`)
- for each page render i just query once the database for taking this row of selected language, and call `json_decode()` to the whole result to get it once; then put it in a **$_SESSION** so the next time to *get flash-speed translated strings* for current selected language.

the whole thing was developed having i mind both **performance and compatibility**.

Answer (score 1):

1. The benefit for storing on the HDD vs DB is that backups won't waste as much space. eg. once the file is backed-up once, it doesn't take up tape on the next day. Whereas, a db gets fully backed up every day and takes up increasing amounts of space.  The down-side to writing it to the disk is that it increases your chance of somebody uploading something malicious and they might be clever enough to figure out how to execute it.  You just need to be more careful, that's all.
2. Yes, use .htaccess to limit any action on a writable folder.  Good job thinking ahead of that risk.
3. Your approach sounds like a good strategy.
   Good luck.